# How can i add default user to object when the user who created the object was deleted

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have Model `Tasks` contains `user` foreign key when user deleted , how can i add another user to that object as a backup user when creator is deleted ?

```
first_user = User.objects.get(username='nagah')


class Task(models.Model):
    taskname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default=first_user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [overriding](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) the `save()` method of your model `Task`

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    # your fields here

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # check if it's an existing object with no user
        if self.id and not self.user:
            first_user = User.objects.get(username='nagah')
            self.user = first_user
        super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What about the FK field as "Task" Model, ?
user =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=get_backup_user, null=True) ?? 
that is caused on error 
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: tasks_task.user_id